Unknown type: "journald" for id: "journald" - OTLP Receiver
I'm trying to figure out how to properly configure my receivers for journald. When I, naively, run otelcol --config=my-config.yaml I'm getting
Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:
* error decoding 'receivers': unknown type: "journald" for id: "journald" (valid values: [prometheus zipkin nop otlp hostmetrics jaeger kafka opencensus])

My config looks something along the lines of:
...

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 127.0.0.1:4318
  journald:
    directory: /var/log/journal
    priority: info

...


To whomever minus rated the question: A constructive comment might have better results in a community, opposed to just using the -1 button

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [sf], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

I turned out to be a misread of documentation. While the honeycomb gives an example using the journald receiver they do state that one should use the opentelemetry-collector-contrib project and not the core OTLP which does not support such receiver :)
